# Awaiting httpclient

Tags: c#

Here is the code -

VERSION 3: Remove r.result and it still doesn't work.

```
protected async void LogIn(LoginInfo _credentials)
{
    HttpResponseMessage r = await DoLogin("demo", "Abc123$");

    if (r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        AccountAccess aa = new AccountAccess();

            var x = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            aa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountAccess>(x);
            Application.Current.Properties["access_token"] = aa.access_token;

    }
    else //if (lr == LoginResult.LoginRes.NoAuth)
    {
        Alert("Alert", "Username/password combination is incorrect", "OK");
    }
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoLogin(string username, string password)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.LOGINURL);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("Token", new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password, Encoding.UTF8));

    return response;
}
```

The await call to post the username and password and get a token never returns.

Am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: Since your method is already async, there is no point in using `Task.Run()`.

Comment: try this method instead 

`public async Task<string> PerformLogin()
    {
        var r = await DoLogin(_username, _password));
        if (r.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //do success stuff
        }
        else
        {
            return "No Auth";
        }
        return "Ok";
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing `r.Result`, which blocks on the Task, on the UI thread.
This creates a deadlock, since the inner `await` tries to resume on the UI thread.

You need to `await` it instead.

Comment: I restructured this and removed r.Result and it still doesn't work. See my updates above.

Comment: Why not? What happens? What did you do?

Comment: My changes are above.. I can prove that after aa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject... aa is empty

Comment: You're making the same mistake again with `ReadAsStringAsync().Result`.  But that isn't causing that particular problem.  Check your response.

Comment: How else do I get result of the HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: You need to `await` it.  You should never use `.Result`.

Comment: That means your server isn't sending what you want it to send.  Use your debugger (or Fiddler) to see what response you're getting.

Comment: I'd normally use Fiddler, but this is integrating into a Xamarin app, so I can't capture any of the traffic. Even with my previous  .Result s, it worked through VS and when I deployed from VS.